# Images disappearing at mobile size

Tags: css

I've been working with an html theme and just noticed that a couple of images are disappearing at mobile size (display fine at desktop). It is the sections where there is a full half page of text and then the other half of the page is filled with an image. Eg: The image that you can see next to this section - Mobile nail clipping for cats and rabbits.

https://amberpollypets.co.uk/mobile-nail-clipping-dogs.html

There are a few styles applied to the image I think: section-media, section-media-half, section-media-half-right and when I look at the stylesheet: style.css there are a few lines of code for these styles.

I tried altering the code under @media (min-width:992px) .section-media-half > img {display: none;} to {display: block;} but nothing changed. Maybe I need to target a smaller screen size?

Any help gratefully received with thanks

```
/* Media (BG) */
.section-media-bg > * {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

/* Media (Half) */
.section-media-half {
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 72px;
}
.section-media-half > * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {

    .section-media-half {
        margin: 0;
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .section-media-half-left {
        left: 0;
        right: auto;
    }
    .section-media-half-right {
        left: auto;
        right: 0;
    }
    
    .section-media-half > img {
        display: none;
    }

    .section-media-half > .gmap-block,
    .section-media-half > .gmap-block > .map {
        height: 100% !important;
    }

    .section-media-half + .container {
        max-width: 50%;
        padding-left: 72px;
        padding-right: 72px;
    }
    .section-media-half-left + .container {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    .section-media-half-right + .container {
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

}
@media (min-width: 1400px) {

    .section-media-half + .container {
        padding-left: 108px;
        padding-right: 108px;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason of those cute dogs image size reduced to half is this code

```
-webkit-background-size: 110% !important; 
-moz-background-size: 110% !important;
-o-background-size: 110% !important;
 background-size: 110% !important;
```

inside the .desktop-device .parallax-section

replace your code with this code

```
.desktop-device .parallax-section {
background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
background-attachment: fixed !important;
/* -webkit-background-size: 110% !important; */
/* -moz-background-size: 110% !important;*/
/*-o-background-size: 110% !important;*/
/* background-size: 110% !important;*/
}
```

or you can remove this

```
-webkit-background-size: 110% !important; 
-moz-background-size: 110% !important;
-o-background-size: 110% !important;
 background-size: 110% !important;
```

code too.

Hope this will help

Bonus info:
your image size is too much which is not good for seo convert your image from jpg format to webp it will increase your website speed